# how add element to scrollmenu html with js function

Tags: javascript, html

i have a scroll menu , and in my java script file i read some data from database and i want to add this data to the scrollmenu.
im very new to web development and i donnt have any notion anout what i have to do.
i need for example a funtion that add a new item to the scrollmenu, and it shold be clickable.

this is  the html code.

```
<html>
    <div class="scrollmenu" id = "scroll">
        <a href="#col1">Home</a>`      
        <a href="#col2">News</a>
  <!-- i want to add at the javascript col3 -->
    </div>

</html>
```

Comment: Please edit your question so that it results in a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with an adding item button, basically you listen for a click on the `Add a new item` button and then you perform the action of adding a new link item in the menu :

```js
var el = document.getElementById('addItem');
el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 var menu = document.getElementById('scroll');
  var a = document.createElement('a');
 a.setAttribute('href', '#col3');
 a.innerHTML = 'New Item';
 menu.appendChild(a);
});
```

```html
    <button id="addItem">
    Add a new item
    </button>
    <br><br>
    <div class="scrollmenu" id = "scroll">
        <a href="#col1">Home</a>   
        <a href="#col2">News</a>
    </div>
```

If you want it to be more dynamic, you can create a function and pass the link's text and href as parameters like so :

```js
var el = document.getElementById('addItem');
el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 addNewItem('New Link', '#col3');
});

function addNewItem(itemText, itemLink) {
 var menu = document.getElementById('scroll');
  var a = document.createElement('a');
 a.setAttribute('href', itemLink);
 a.innerHTML = itemText;
 menu.appendChild(a);
}
```

```html
    <button id="addItem">
    Add a new item
    </button>
    <br><br>
    <div class="scrollmenu" id = "scroll">
        <a href="#col1">Home</a>   
        <a href="#col2">News</a>
    </div>
```